# Trouble in fetching data from next pages using post requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from below website . The tables are split into various pages but all of the pages use the same url. I am using Requests, pandas and BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML code and I am able to scrape the initial table only , but I want the entire data from all tables.

Note I am trying to use only Pandas , Beautifulsoup and requests ....not Selenium Note this website shows data at particular time and pages rage from 0 to 9 or sometimes 10,15

I have written program but it extracts only 1st table, I wanna extract data from all pages . please help me

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

params = {                   #Console
    "pos": " ",
    "stats": " ",
    "type": " "
}

data = {                                # Network --> Request 
    "__EVENTTARGET" : "grdMWCG@ctl29",   #grdMWCG$ctl29$ctl00
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': "",    #'FireCommand:grdMWCG$ctl29;PageSize;1000',
   #'__VIEWSTATE' : "qI7kN0JsQhV3qLHXe45eUTDT1YiA+R/k6VJkLSCL++BAyoKgHIgYgPbr+q/NsFwQ5BHwqPkAeV25qNkOUOoz3vfYWD1d77cTyCM4sJKinGsyC9FfPkqSEPT5lEOhkP41a3Xo1GywCFbapgM83hXY5/Lu/RrQAjLNdEUwsg+dj/WHn+aE",
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': "00145D45",
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':""
   #'__EVENTVALIDATION': "41pWf5gO9W1jt4YKQK30WKaHlv3pGh+kaJAUpRk5MkyZqR/AauHgJ5YEFWg9DjwtQNxwXWSH6QbNwjgOjgyI2fkLOtSbFu0r9JuA+dXqtmvLUuIHECQv8HNH+8a1c179u6QvlBSsSMzIvpfJNPPu7ats04coyA3FHDghbZPDWqREQeq5"
}

def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
      # r = req.get(url, params=params)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value")
        #r = req.post(url, params=params, data=data)
        r = req.post(url ,  data=data)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                          'id': 'grdMWCG'})[0]          #Table id  #grdMWCG
        #df.drop(df.columns[3], axis=1, inplace=True)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("ccil.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.ccilindia.com/OMMWCG.aspx")
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

So to get the data from all pages you need to request them.

When you look at the code that is called when you manually click on the page you find that it will call the __doPostBack function:

```html
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('grdMWSG$ctl29$ctl01','')" style="color:#35496A;">2</a>
```

This function will enter values in the form fields and submits the form.

```js
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

The page number is stored in the value of the function call:

```
grdMWSG$ctl29$ctl01 // page 2
```

You should make a loop that goes through the numbers of pages and make a request and extract the data.

This code will request the first page, extract the number of pages, updates the post fields and request the data from all of the pages.

<del>It only prints the data. If you want to save it you have to add the pd.to_csv call.</del>

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

params = {                   #Console
    "pos": " ",
    "stats": " ",
    "type": " "
}

data = {                             
    "__EVENTTARGET" : "",
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',  
    "__VIEWSTATE" : "",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": "",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": "",
    
    
}


# Update the data Fields with new Values 
# For fields that can't be found the exception can be ignored 
def updateData(response):
    global data 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in data: 
        try:
            data[i] = soup.find("input", id=i).get("value")
        except:
             pass
            #print(i)

def main(url):
    global data 
    targetString = "grdMWCG$ctl29$ctl0"
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                      'id': 'grdMWCG'})[0]          

        # Print Table of First Page 
        print(df)
        
        # get the last element of the last colum, where the current page count is stored 
        # The 26 is a magic number I don't know if it will always be 26
        pageLength = int(df[0][26][-1])
        
        updateData(r)
        
        for pageNumber in range(1,pageLength):
            data["__EVENTTARGET"] = targetString+str(pageNumber)
            r = req.post(url ,  data=data)
            _df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                          'id': 'grdMWCG'})[0]          
            updateData(r)        
            df = df.append(_df)
        df.to_csv("ccild.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.ccilindia.com/OMMWCG.aspx")
```

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you Sir . Kindly just assist me , how to print all data in CSV , I tried it but it only prints data from last page.

Comment: you habe to store the data somewhere and then save to csv. if you add the save call after every print call it will override the old csv file

Comment: i have changed it to save it now

Comment: Working perfectly, Really thanks for your help. In fact many developers told me that it is not possible to extract data from this website without selenium. I also tried  program with selenium ,it works  but it is very slow. Really thank you so much.

Comment: @TechBro is there a problem or other thing not working  ?

Comment: No Sir,  it is working perfectly